# "Error: Duplicate Resources" while building Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin

This the error I'm getting :

```
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
/Users/vedantdasswain/GitRepositories/EnergyLens/AndroidStudioVersion/EnergyLens/app/src/main/res/values/themes_apptheme.xml
Error:Error: Duplicate resources: /Users/vedantdasswain/GitRepositories/EnergyLens/AndroidStudioVersion/EnergyLens/app/src/main/res/values/themes_apptheme.xml:style/AppTheme, /Users/vedantdasswain/GitRepositories/EnergyLens/AndroidStudioVersion/EnergyLens/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:style/AppTheme
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/vedantdasswain/GitRepositories/EnergyLens/AndroidStudioVersion/EnergyLens/app/src/main/res/values/themes_apptheme.xml: Error: Duplicate resources: /Users/vedantdasswain/GitRepositories/EnergyLens/AndroidStudioVersion/EnergyLens/app/src/main/res/values/themes_apptheme.xml:style/AppTheme, /Users/vedantdasswain/GitRepositories/EnergyLens/AndroidStudioVersion/EnergyLens/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:style/AppTheme
```

The source of this error is the following file, themes_apptheme.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/_AppTheme"/>

  <style name="_AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#99003366</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/apptheme_text_select_handle_left</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/apptheme_text_select_handle_right</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/apptheme_text_select_handle_middle</item>

    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewAppTheme</item>

    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/apptheme_btn_check_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/apptheme_btn_radio_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>

    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonAppTheme</item>

    <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerAppTheme</item>

    <item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/apptheme_list_selector_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/apptheme_activated_background_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/apptheme_fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>

  </style>

</resources>
```

Could someone please explain what is causing the error and how to resolve it?

**UPDATE:**

The duplicate resource was mentioned in styles.xml, which I commented out:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <!--<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">-->
        <!--&lt;!&ndash; All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--</style>-->


</resources>
```

This seems to have let me complete the build successfully and solve the problem. Thanks for the comment @pyus13

Comment: seems like you have AppTheme in both your styles.xml and themes_apptheme.xml please include content of bith file in question.

Answer (score 2):

Variable `Apptheme` in both `themes_apptheme.xml` and `styles.xml` cannot remain the same name, because `Apptheme` in `themes_apptheme.xml` refers to `styles.xml` anyway.
Just delete one of them or modify it.